# Generating multinomial random data in R

Tags: r, random, simulation, multinomial

I am trying to generate data from a multinomial distribution in R using the function rmultinom, but I am having some problems.
The fact is that I want a data frame of 50 rows and 20 columns and a total sum of the outcomes equal to 3 times n*p.

I am using this code:

```
p <- 20
n <- 50
N <- 3*(n*p)
prob_true <- rep(1/p, p)
a <- rmultinom(50, N, prob_true)
```

But I get some very strange results and a data frame with 20 rows and 50 columns.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help available at `?rmultinom` says that `n` in `rmultinom(n, size, prob)` is:

"number of random vectors to draw"

And `size` is:
"specifying the total number of objects that are put into K boxes in the typical multinomial experiment"

And the help says that the output is:
"For rmultinom(), an integer K x n matrix where each column is a random vector generated according to the desired multinomial law, and hence summing to size"

So you're asking for 50 vectors/variables with a total number of "objects" equal to 3000, so each column is drawn as a vector that sums to 3000.

`colSums(a)` does result in `3000`.

Do you want your vectors/variables as rows? Then this would work just by transposing `a`:

```
t(a)
```

but if you want 20 columns, each that is its own variable, you would need to switch your `n` and `p` (I also subbed in `n` in the `rmultinom` call):

```
n <- 20
p <- 50
N <- 3*(n*p)
prob_true <- rep(1/p, p)
a <- rmultinom(n, N, prob_true)
```